# classList.add works but toggle doesn't

Tags: javascript, arrays, toggle

My HTML

```
<div class="chapter">text text text </div>
<div class="chapter">text text text </div>
<button id="button">button</button>
```

My js

```
var button = document.querySelector('#button');
var chapter = document.querySelectorAll('.chapter');
for(var i = 0; i < chapter.length; i++){
button.addEventListener('click', function(){

for(var i = 0; i < chapter.length; i++) {
chapter[i].classList.add('active');
}
});
}
```

This adds the class of "active" on clicking the button.

But toggle doesn't work.  Instead of

```
chapter[i].classList.add('active');
```

When I do,

```
chapter[i].classList.toggle('active');
```

the class of "active" does not toggle.  console shows no error.

So I tried to check the class of "active" first & remove the class if the class exists.  I know I was trying to reinvent the toggle function; as stated above, toggle wasn't working so I tried it anyway.

```
if (chapter[i].contains('active')){
chapter[i].classList.remove('active');
```

And I got a slew of error messages.  This is as far as I got.  I somehow felt that this wasn't going to work but just tried it anyway.

I am stumped.

Can anyone point out why classList.toggle isn't working in my code & how this can be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error/errors that you see ?

Comment: @Sushanth, none.  When I change "add" to "toggle", no error message shows on the console.  Nothing happens & the class doens't toggle.

Comment: If the above is the actual code you're using, it looks like you might be calling  the contains method on the wrong object. It should be if (chapter[i].classList.contains('active')){
chapter[i].classList.remove('active');

Comment: Your loops look weird to me, I don't understand what you want to achieve with them. Please explain the desired behavior. What exactly should happen when you click on the button? And if you click again?

Comment: @Chris Guierrez, the second part is something I just threw in to see what happens.  I have no desire to reinvent the toggle function.

Comment: @blex, here is what I wish to achieve.  When I click a button, a class of "active" is added to a class of  elements ("chapter"),  On clicking the button again, the class of "active" is removed.

I thought this was a classic toggle function?  I don't know how a toggle function can be "weird."

Comment: I did not undertand why you had the outer loop. That confused me on what you wanted to achieve. I think I got it now. Check my answer to see if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one too many loop. Remove the outer one:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#button');
var chapter = document.querySelectorAll('.chapter');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  for(var i = 0; i < chapter.length; i++) {
    chapter[i].classList.toggle('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.active{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="chapter">text text text </div>
<div class="chapter">text text text </div>
<div class="chapter">text text text </div>
<div class="chapter">text text text </div>
<button id="button">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#button');
var chapters = document.querySelectorAll('.chapter');

  button.addEventListener('click', function(){
   for(var index = 0; index < chapters.length; index++) {
      if(chapters[index].classList.contains('active')){
        chapters[index].classList.remove('active');
      }else{
        chapters[index].classList.add('active');
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="chapter">text text text </div>
<div class="chapter">text text text </div>
<button id="button">Toggle Color</button>
```